# uTorrent WebAPI, adding tokens to actions? Set up a session?

Tags: android, session, web, utorrent

I'm completing my uTorrent remote client for android. However just as I'm adding actions I realized I cannot add tokens to the URL of actions.

This is how the URL requests that gives me a list of torrents looks like: http://IP:PORT/gui/?list=0&token=J0oojF7e-GPgZJRyyxGSvMuA-Rn_wC2G80TpkfupLbXuc1WRb4yUaRUvYVgAAAAA

As you can see you just add the token and the request goes through. However, there is no session. So I thought I'd just add the token to every request. However this seems to not be possible with the rest of the requests(or is it!?).

This is an example of a request I need to do `HTTP://[IP]:[PORT]/GUI/?ACTION=START&HASH=[TORRENT HASH]`

I cannot add a token there. Adding the cookie header seems to not set up a session either. Is there a way to make my app keep up a session like a browser. So the WebAPI won't ask for token every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank god. It's possible. Just do it this way:

http://IP:PORT/GUI/?TOKEN=xxx&ACTION=START&HASH=zzz